# TensorFlow 2 in Google Colabs Failed Preconditioned Error on Model Test

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to call predict() on my full model and passing it the test data batch. The model works on my training and validation data, but I get this error when I try to run it on my test data.

I've reviewed the answers on the stack overflow link, but I cannot make the connection on why I keep getting the error.

Here is the function I run:

```
# Make predictions on test data batch using the loaded full model
test_predictions = loaded_full_model.predict(test_data,
                                             verbose=1)
```

And here is the error returned:

```
 14/324 [>.............................] - ETA: 39s
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-1081792ff13f> in <module>()
      1 # Make predictions on test data batch using the loaded full model
      2 test_predictions = loaded_full_model.predict(test_data,
----> 3                                              verbose=1)

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, 
num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

FailedPreconditionError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Failed precondition:  /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/test/.ipynb_checkpoints; Is a 
directory
     [[{{node ReadFile}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[IteratorGetNext/_2]]
  (1) Failed precondition:  /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/test/.ipynb_checkpoints; Is a 
directory
     [[{{node ReadFile}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_predict_function_189545]

Function call stack:
predict_function -> predict_function
```

Comment: Looks like its not able to locate the test data, can ensure you are loading test data correctly by printing it?

Comment: I am able to access the data. Here is the code:# Load test image filenames
test_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/test/"
test_filenames = [test_path + fname for fname in os.listdir(test_path)]
test_filenames[:10]

Comment: Here was the abbreviated output:                                                        
                                                                                                             ['/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/test/f6bb9fedf0b41301d3c6016a25c51608.jpg']